# Leaflet - Anchor tags in pop-up?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to bind a function to a anchor tag link inside a leaflet pop-up but it seems like you cant do this with leaflet. I would like to bind a on-click function to an ID or CLASS which opens a jquery dialog / modal with more information.

Is there an alternative solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/): since Leaflet's popups are only created when a user clicks on a feature, you can't bind events on their contents off the bat, since they don't exist yet. If you use `.on` with a selector, you can bind to the event whenever it happens.

Comment: Just some clarification.. Do you mean attach the .on function to the end of the bindpopup("content..")? Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/clicks-in-popups/

Comment: Yes of course the #map .on not the popup .on! Works great now! Really nice of you to give me an example! Not always easy to find help on leaflet or maps in general!